# How to run a web process without opening browser in c#

Tags: c#, web-services, url

i want to run a web process without opening web browser. I want to update the entry but when i click the button i dont want to open a web page.

Example:

on button click

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://example.com/_change_status.php?id=67&new_status=2");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute WebRequest without need to start a process. If all your application requires is to make that URL be accessed on the server, than that is the way to go.

Comment: can you give me an example please?

Comment: Here you can find the code: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/456dfw4f(v=vs.110).aspx